# How to start Kamailio on boot

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, kamailio, systemctl

I am trying to start the Kamailio Service on Ubuntu when the system boots. I have tried using the commands "service kamailio enable" and "systemctl enable kamailio.service," but the service still does not start on boot. Any help would be appreciated, thank you and have a great one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start or stop kamailo service:

```
systemctl start kamailio
systemctl stop kamailio
```

To configure a service to run at startup :

```
sudo update-rc.d kamailio defaults
sudo update-rc.d kamailio enable
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, I appreciate it, :)!